# How to create the data as an array of object with limit of 5 data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to create the data as an array of objects with a limit of 5 data in JavaScript.

I am using web socket and getting this call first time

```
[
    {city:"Newyork",value:10,"time":"13:8"},
    {city:"London",value:20,"time":"13:8"}
]
```

Now In the second call, I will get data like that

```
[
    {city:"Newyork",value:150,"time":"13:20"},
    {city:"London",value:25,"time":"13:20"}
    {city:"Sydney",value:20,"time":"13:20"}
]
```

So what I am doing here is I am adding new data and updating the existing data and then updating my state. Here is the code for that.

```
var city = this.state.city;

for(var j=0; j<res.length; j++){
    const i = city.findIndex(_item => _item.city === res[j].city);
    if (i > -1) city[i] = res[j]; // (2)
    else city.push(res[j]);
}
            
this.setState({data:city})
```

This is working fine.

Now How I declare a state where I have to update five data which based on the last five WebSocket call.

Somewhat like this

```
myData = [{newyork:{[value:10,time:13:20],[value:150,time:13:20]}},London:{[value:20,time:13:20],[value:25,time:13:20]},Sydney:{[value:20,time:13:20]}];
```

So Based on this data I can plot a chart of a specific city. I need only 5 data of each city.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Let me get this straight: You want to create an array with a limit of 5 values. If you want to do that, you can just manually set the length by doing `myData.length = 5`.

Comment: @Capt171 I want each city should have 5 key value pair of time and value. IT will keep updating with the new value.

Comment: You can set `city.length = Math.min(5, city.length)` after each update

Comment: So you want to always save the 5 latest data points for each city in the array, and when a sixth data point comes in, you want to add that data point and also remove the oldest data point. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: yes @EmilKarlsson I want to remove old and get update with new Data. Also in a such way that it is easy to read or search with city name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each update, for each city, you can do something like this:

```
if(city[city_name].length >= 5){
    city[city_name].shift();
}

city[city_name].push(new_city);
```

Comment: THank u for anser let me trt=y